# How can I set up the pivot_table options to get total and percentage?

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I am practicing the pivot_table. I want to calculate the numbers of "good" and "bad" and also get the percentage of each.

This is the image that I would like to have.
How can I set up the pivot_table options?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this instance, you wouldn't need a pivot table because you're just summing over one variable. An easy way to achieve what you're after would be:

```
A = ['good','good','bad','good',np.nan]
Data = pd.DataFrame(A)
Data.columns = ['Status']
Data.index=['x1','x2','x3','x4','x5']


counts = Data.Status.value_counts().to_frame('total')
counts['percentage'] = counts.total / 
counts.total.sum()
```

To do the same thing with a pivot table, I think you'd need to introduce a dummy variable to sum over. And either way, you'd still have to calculate the percentage afterwards:

```
Data['total'] = 1
piv = Data.pivot_table(
    index='Status',
    values='total',
    aggfunc='sum'
)
piv['percentage'] = piv.total/piv.total.sum(axis=0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I can understand the way you showed but I would like to use the pivot table just for practice. So if you know how to do the same job with the pivot table, please let me know.

Comment: This is exactly what I intended. I really appreciated it.